# How exactly does mod_rewrite work when displaying old url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have used mod_rewrite to change `http://mywebsite.com/?page=2` to `http://mywebsite.com/page/2` using the following code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)\.php$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

But when i type in the old url -  `http://mywebsite.com/?page=2` the page still appears and the url doesnt change to the static one. Is mod-rewrite meant to redirect the user or just make everything on the dynamic url appear on the static one when entered? If so how can i redirect any user that goes to the old dynamic url - `http://mywebsite.com/?page=2` to the new static one `http://mywebsite.com/page/2`? Plus does google still index the old url?

This is my complete .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

    # external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
    RewriteCond \s/+\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=301,L]

    # existing rule
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` just provides virtual *incoming* URLs/paths. Additional rules could add redirects for old path schemes. But it's commonly expected to adapt HTML templates and outbound URLs instead, or use `mod_substitute`.

Comment: So when someone types in the old dynamic url, should they still be able to see the original page with the old dynamic url? Does that mean google will still index that page then?

Comment: Both work. And yes, as long as links to the old path scheme exist, search engines may index them.

Comment: Do you know of a way to prevent this? Since i only want google to index my static urls? Thanks for your help Mario!

Comment: Provide a [`<link rel=canonical>`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en), and/or add aforementioned parmanent redirects for the old path scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your full .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=301,L]

# existing rule
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: When i add that and go to the old url, the url doesn't change? this is the link to my site.. (http://bigfatgiveaways.com/?page=2) and i wish it to change from that link to /page/2. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: My first 301 rule exactly that, it will redirect `/?page=2` to `/page/2`. What is location of above .htaccess file?

Comment: I have exactly what you have written above in my .htaccess file and it is places in my public_html file but it doesn't redirect the user?

Comment: Looks like you have more stuff in your current .htaccess. Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question (not in comments)

Comment: It works great now brilliant! What was i doing wrong? Should i change all the links in my html/php to the static one as the redirect slows down the page?

Comment: Yes definitely update your links like `/page/2`. There were couple of issues 1. I had a typo and skipped `%{THE_REQUEST}` in my condition. 2. Adding `.php` rule should be last one.

Comment: This works great, but for some reason it has dramatically slowed down my website when loading any page that involves the .htaccess file? Why is this and do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Rewrite rules in itself cannot dramatically slow down a website. There might be something else. Can you open your http request in Firebug and trace it.

Comment: I have fixed the problem, it was a couple of incorrectly altered links. Thanks for your help you have been great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` necessarily will not redirect the visitor to the new fancy URL, but it will make sure that anybody who visits the new URL will still access it as if it is using the old URL

I believe you can achieve something like that with `mod_substitute`, but that's not something I will advice you to do now.

If you can, manually change the links to reflect the new changes, or have a function which will parse out your links such as

```
http://mywebsite.com/?page=2 to http://mywebsite.com/page/2
```

such as

```
function fancyuri($url){
    //blah blah, strip out ? and change all occurence of equality sign = to forward slash
    //do some other tricks
    //return formatted links 
}
```

And then pass your links as a param to the function and have it return your nice urls, in this case, even if you don't want it again, you can strip off the formatting codes in the function and still have ur original url returned.